# Is there simple way to get query for dbix::class result?

Tags: sql, perl, dbix-class

If I want to log queries I may use something like [DBIx::Class::QueryLog](http://search.cpan.org/~gphat/DBIx-Class-QueryLog-1.3.3/lib/DBIx/Class/QueryLog.pm)

But how can I get the resulting query only once for one result?

```
$db->resultset('Pool::Address')->search(
  {'server.locality_id' => $self->id, usage => 0, 'destination.id' => undef},
    {join => ['destination', {subnet => 'server'}], order_by => 'ip'}
 )->get_query()   ???
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must use ResultSet method [->as_query](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/DBIx-Class-0.082820/lib/DBIx/Class/ResultSet.pm#as_query)

Comment: Also consider using `$schema->storage->debug(1)`.